# Hide a sheet when it's no longer active with gscript in google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used to use VBA in Ms Excel for hiding a sheet when it's no longer an active sheet (code below)[image]

Now I'm using a google sheet and I'm trying to find a way to do the same task. Anyone know how ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "it's no longer an active sheet"? Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hey Ruben,

So, I have 5 sheet (Sheet 1,Sheet 2,Sheet 3,Sheet 4,Sheet 5) in one file of google sheet, when I'm working or go to sheet 1, the others 4 sheets are not active.

On excel I'm using the code above to hide a sheet when the sheet is not active, but I don't know how to do it in google sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  e.source.getSheets().forEach(s => {
    if (!s.isSheetHidden() && s.getName() != name) {
      s.hideSheet();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Dear Cooper, Thank you, in my case i just need basically the trigger, ten i figured out the other solution and it works :). But your answer helps me anyway :)